# flask-admin: How to display meaningful foreign key info in edit and create forms?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a Flask-Admin interface to a flask app using SQLAlechemy, and I can't seem to figure out how to handle foreign keys. Specifically, I have the following two models:

```
class DoctorType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'doctor_type'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    doctor_type_english_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    doctors = db.relationship('Doctor')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.doctor_type_english_name

class Doctor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'doctor'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    doctor_english_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    doctor_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('doctor_type.id'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.doctor_english_name
```

I'd like for the doctor_type_id field in the create or edit forms of flask-admin to be a dropdown list of doctor_type_english_name rather than just being an integer input like this:

[Doctor Type Input Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JYgp.png)

I have `__unicode__` functions on the models (I'm using python 2.7). I tried tinkering with form_ajax_refs in my custom form views but with no success. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out what I was missing was a relationship from the Doctor class to the DoctorType class. I implemented this with a backref in the DoctorType.doctors relationship:

```
class DoctorType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'doctor_type'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    doctor_type_english_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    doctors = db.relationship('Doctor', backref='doctor_type')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.doctor_type_english_name
```

Once I added that, the "Doctor" edit and create forms in flask-admin had a new field called Doctor Type that was a dropdown of the DoctorType.doctor_type_english_name values, and the Doctor Type ID field was gone by default. This is the behavior I was wanting.

Answer (score 13):

Implement `__repr__` in define of data model.

```
class DoctorType(db.Model):
    #...
    def __repr__(self):
        return self. doctor_type_english_name
```

Comment: Adding `__repr__` would not help since that does the same thing as the `__unicode__` function in this case. The foreign key still shows up as an integer field in the edit and delete forms. Thanks for the speedy response though!

Comment: Have you try implement `__repr__` in your model define? `__repr__` and `__unicode__` both works for me.

Comment: I did. I realized it was the relationship that was missing, not the `__repr__`. Thanks again for the answer though! I upvoted your answer but I don't have enough rep to upvote anything yet :-(

Comment: This is wonderful. It works like a charm, with so little code!